# Is there a way to efficiently update one value in dojo chart2d?

Tags: dojo, graph

I am looking for a way to update one and only one value in a dojox chart2d.  There is a way to update an entire series, which involves

```
mychart.updateSeries("myseriesname",array_of_data)
mychart.render()
```

but This is too slow for my application.

What I want to do is be able to drag the mouse over a vertical bar chart and have the values change as I am doing it.  Only one or two values will need to change, so there is no need to reload all of the plots, just the two or three values that are changing.

Is there a method that will quickly update only one or two values without lag?

Thanks,
Nick O

I may just end up writing my own css version :S

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to update just one value. If you feel this is an important use case, common for different applications, please open an enhancement ticket on http://bugs.dojotoolkit.com